# Should I replace an old breaker or add a new one?

Tags: water-heater, circuit-breaker

Our old circuit breaker for our water heater seems to be at the end of its life. However, the breaker also controls our well system, and the breaker is only 20 amps. Is it okay for us to just replace the breaker (the old one lasted a good 15-20 years) or should we consider having an electrician separate out the well onto a new circuit? There is an open slot in the circuit box if needed.

Comment: Double tapping a breaker is to be avoided, even if it's rated for it, most municipalities will not allow it. You may need to replace a breaker with a single-gang duel-breaker, to make *2* open slots for an extra double-gang (220) one.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely have the two circuit separated. In fact, they should have been from the start.

If the water heater is a "standard" 4500 watt tank-type then a 20A breaker is not adequate anyway. You'd need #10 wire with a 30A two-pole breaker.

Comment: I pulled back the cover on the breaker box to take a look inside, since the set-up was so odd. The breaker is a 2-pole 2-inch breaker with two black wires, a red, and a white connected. And above that, an unlabeled 20-amp breaker was revealed to have no wire connected to it at all. Perhaps they put the second black wire into the wrong breaker? If so, is there a safe way to find out without calling in an electrician?